# Why Qt does not produce at least a warning for the missing slot?

Tags: c++, qt

I have spent some time with finding an error, in connection wit slots and signals. I copied some connect() lines from another file, and I relied on the compiler to find out which objects I need to define in my new class, so I added them. The 'this' object should not be edited, so I did not care providing the corresponding slots. The program compiles OK, an even without warnigns. But -in lack of slots- does not run.

Considering the (sometimes too) strict type checking, why does not produce Qt at least a warning? (at compile time it can know for sure, that no such slot exists.)

Comment: Old signal/slot syntax is based on run time string comparison. It's good/bad/ugly for all different reasons. Use new syntax if you want compile time check. However if you use old syntax Qt does give run time error to the console output when a connection fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, new functor-based connections does checking at compile-time, so in case of some invalid signal/slot the app will not even compile

So, to check it during compile time you just need to use functor-based type of connection:

```
connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged,
            doubleSpinBox, &QDoubleSpinBox::setValue);
```

instead of string-based:

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
        doubleSpinBox, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

You can read here in details:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html